# Validation accuracy initially high then low

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, text-classification

I am training a model for text sentiment classification with CNN. In it, the validation accuracy is initially more than training accuracy and then it decreases. Is this behavior acceptable? If not then what can be the reason and how to solve it?

[image]

My model:

```
class hyper():
  def __init__(self,embedding_dim,filter_sizes,num_filters,dropout_prob,hidden_dims,batch_size,num_epochs):
    # Model Hyperparameters
    self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim
    self.filter_sizes = filter_sizes
    self.num_filters = num_filters
    self.dropout_prob = dropout_prob
    self.hidden_dims = hidden_dims
    # Training parameters
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.num_epochs = num_epochs

class prep_hyper():
  def __init__(self,sequenceLength,max_words):
    # Prepossessing parameters
    self.sequenceLength = sequenceLength
    self.max_words = max_words
    
m_hyper=hyper(embedding_dim=embed_dim,filter_sizes=(3,4,5,6,8),num_filters=80,dropout_prob=(0.2,0.5),
              hidden_dims=50,batch_size=128,num_epochs= 30)

pr_hyper = prep_hyper(sequenceLength=sequence_length,max_words=vocab_size)
```

model architecture:

```
def build_model(pr_hyper,m_hyper):
    
    # Convolutional block
    model_input = Input(shape=(pr_hyper.sequenceLength))
    # use a random embedding for the text
    x = Embedding(pr_hyper.max_words, m_hyper.embedding_dim,weights=[emb],trainable=False)(model_input)
#     x = SpatialDropout1D(m_hyper.dropout_prob[0])(x)

    conv_kern_reg = regularizers.l2(0.0001)
    conv_bias_reg = regularizers.l2(0.0001)
    
    conv_blocks = []
    for sz in m_hyper.filter_sizes:
        conv = Convolution1D(filters=m_hyper.num_filters,
                             kernel_size=sz,
#                              padding="same",
                             activation="relu",
                             strides=1,
                             kernel_regularizer=conv_kern_reg,
                             bias_regularizer=conv_bias_reg
                            )(x)
        conv = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(conv)
        conv_blocks.append(conv)
    # merge
    x = Concatenate()(conv_blocks) if len(conv_blocks) > 1 else conv_blocks[0]
    
    x = Dense(m_hyper.hidden_dims, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dropout(m_hyper.dropout_prob[1])(x)
    x = Dense(100, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dropout(m_hyper.dropout_prob[1])(x)
    model_output = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(x)
    model = Model(model_input, model_output)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00005), metrics=["accuracy"]) #categorical_crossentropy
    print(model.summary())
    tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)#, to_file='multichannel.png')
    return model
```

[image]

INITIAL EPOCHS:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons that this happens, like, the dropout layers is disabled during validation. For more information I would suggest you to see [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/14/why-is-my-validation-loss-lower-than-my-training-loss/)
that describes several possible reasons that this happens.